# Using jwnl (Java WordNet Library) concerning file_properties.xml

Tags: java, xml, wordnet

The file_properties needs to be altered for the for the working and adhering to the demo file [here](http://shiffman.net/itp/classes/a2z/wordnet/WordNetDemo.java) 
I have altered it. But still this error persists. I am not very familiar with XML. Can anybody help fix the error which occurs in parsing the file.

Here's the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jwnl_properties language="en"/></jwnl_properties>
<version publisher="Princeton" number="3.0" language="en"/>
<dictionary class="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary">
<param name="dictionary_path" value="C:\Program Files\WordNet-    3.0\2.1\dict\"/>
</dictionary>
    <param name="morphological_processor" value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.DefaultMorphologicalProcessor">
        <param name="operations">
            <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.LookupExceptionsOperation"/>
            <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.DetachSuffixesOperation">
                <param name="noun" value="|s=|ses=s|xes=x|zes=z|ches=ch|shes=sh|men=man|ies=y|"/>
                <param name="verb" value="|s=|ies=y|es=e|es=|ed=e|ed=|ing=e|ing=|"/>
                <param name="adjective" value="|er=|est=|er=e|est=e|"/>
                <param name="operations">
                    <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.LookupIndexWordOperation"/>
                    <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.LookupExceptionsOperation"/>
                </param>
            </param>
            <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.TokenizerOperation">
                <param name="delimiters">
                    <param value=" "/>
                    <param value="-"/>
                </param>
                <param name="token_operations">
                    <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.LookupIndexWordOperation"/>
                    <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.LookupExceptionsOperation"/>
                    <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.DetachSuffixesOperation">
                        <param name="noun" value="|s=|ses=s|xes=x|zes=z|ches=ch|shes=sh|men=man|ies=y|"/>
                        <param name="verb" value="|s=|ies=y|es=e|es=|ed=e|ed=|ing=e|ing=|"/>
                        <param name="adjective" value="|er=|est=|er=e|est=e|"/>
                        <param name="operations">
                            <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.LookupIndexWordOperation"/>
                            <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.LookupExceptionsOperation"/>
                        </param>
                    </param>
                </param>
            </param>
        </param>
    </param>
    <param name="dictionary_element_factory" value="net.didion.jwnl.princeton.data.PrincetonWN17FileDictionaryElementFactory"/>
    <param name="file_manager" value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManagerImpl">
        <param name="file_type" value="net.didion.jwnl.princeton.file.PrincetonRandomAccessDictionaryFile"/>
        <param name="dictionary_path" value="c:\program files\wordnet-3.0\2.0\dict"/>
    </param>
</dictionary>
<resource class="PrincetonResource"/>
</jwnl_properties>
```

And here's the error that occurred when a simple code to obtain the senses of a word was run. There seems to be no error in the program.

```
[Fatal Error] :2:35: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: Error parsing the properties file
at net.didion.jwnl.JWNL.initialize(JWNL.java:117)
at Summarization.main(Summarization.java:46)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 35; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
at net.didion.jwnl.JWNL.initialize(JWNL.java:115)
... 1 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in your XML the `<jwnl_properties>` tag is closed three times, first it's set as empty element (the `/>` at the end), right after that it's closed again with `</jwnl_properties>` and then you get yet another `</jwnl_properties>` at the end of the file.
If you change the second line from

```
<jwnl_properties language="en"/></jwnl_properties>
```

to just

```
<jwnl_properties language="en">
```

the problem should disappear there, but it won't go away completely since, if I'm not mistaken, your `<dictionary>` is also closed twice: in line 6 as well as in third-last one, you need to get rid of one of those. If you do, I think your XML would be well-formed then, though I might've missed something.

Comment: Thank you. I got it solved a few days ago and it had been the exact same problem which you have stated :)